# Lazy<T> why does it get Func<T>

Tags: c#, lazy-loading

Can someone please explain in simple words, why does Lazy in C# needs to get Func?

```
public Lazy (Func<T> valueFactory);
```

I understand that sometime you need a function in order to do some fancy **init()**.
however, many times I find myself writing a singleton, or something simple, where just create a new instance of the class.
As shown in Jon's Skeet book.
http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

I find this syntax to be very annoying.

Thanks!

```
private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());
```

Comment: What would  you like the syntax to look like? The point of `Lazy<T>` is, that `new Singleton()` is only executed at the first access to `lazy`. If the syntax was `new Lazy<Singleton>(new Singleton());` the instance would be created _immediatly_. You need a `Func<T>` that is executed at the first access to `lazy`.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425133/lazy-initialization-in-net-4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't get the `Lazy` to work without the initializer function. That is how it ensures the logic for the creation of the object is there, but not yet called.

Consider this:

```
new Lazy<Singleton>(new Singleton());
```

This already instantiates a new `Singleton`. There is no use for the lazy any more. The function allows `Lazy<T>` to construct the object at any time in the future.

Another plus for the `Func<T>` is that it doesn't need to be a new object it instantiates. It can be anything else. It can be a multi-line statement, a fetch of something else, etc.

One optimization I could argue for is that `new Lazy<T>()` would use the `new()` on `T`, which prevents the need for you to call the constructor. That is however not possible with the current syntax, but it works with a static factory method.

Something like this (and yes, it is basically does what you do now, but then tucked away in the core):

```
public static class LazyDefault
{
    public static Lazy<TNew> New<TNew>() where TNew : new()
    {
        return new Lazy<TNew>(() => new TNew());
    }
}
```

Or as CodeCaster suggested with a derived class:

```
public class SuperLazy<T> : Lazy<T>
    where T : new()
{
    public SuperLazy()
         : base(() => new T())
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: _"new Lazy<T>() would use the new() on T"_ - https://www.ideone.com/ttOhIk - but you basically just wrote the same.

Answer (score 7):

You *need* a func, because if you could do this:

```
var Lazy<Foo> = new Lazy<Foo>(new Foo());
```

You're already instantiating the `Foo`, which you don't want, otherwise you didn't have to use `Lazy<T>` to begin with.

The `Func<T>` holds the initializer for `Foo`, but only initializes it when you access the `Lazy<T>`'s `Value`.

Answer (score 1):

What you give to `Lazy<T>` constructor is known as a *thunk* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk)):

> In computer programming, a thunk is a subroutine used to inject an
>   additional calculation into another subroutine. Thunks are primarily
>   used to delay a calculation until its result is needed, or to insert
>   operations at the beginning or end of the other subroutine. They have
>   a variety of other applications in compiler code generation and
>   modular programming.

That is, the core of *lazy evalutation* is that the whole thing to be evaluated is delayed until it's really required.

If you find annoying having to explicitly provide the `Func<T>`, you may simplify that in the following way:

```
public static class Lazy 
{
     public static Lazy<T> Of<T>()
            where T : class, new() => new Lazy<T>(() => new T())
}


var lazyFoo = Lazy.Of<Foo>()
```

Answer (score 1):

`Lazy` needs a `Func` to actually initialize the inner value. the whole purpose of using Lazy is initializing a value only when its needed. so there should be a way Lazy to actually initialize the value when needed, that's where the `Func` comes in. i don't see any other way to implement something like `Lazy` other than passing a initialization function.